# How should we fix the Monster Lore Compendium question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/136946/was-the-monster-lore-compendium-ever-updated-after-april-6th-2008) is currently hosting an edit war.

- It was originally posted as a D&D 3.5 question, but with an assertion that the Monster Lore Compendium would be added to the d20pfsrd website. This was odd, because d20pfsrd is a Pathfinder resource, not a 3.5 one.
- The querent then edited in a Web Archive link to the source of that claim.
- nijineko, seeing the mention on d20pfsrd, edited to retag the question as Pathfinder, presumably assuming it had originally been mis-tagged.
- John Grabanski then edited it again, reverting the tag to 3.5 and changing the SRD mention to link to d20srd, the 3.5 version.

You can view these changes in the question's [edit history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/136946/revisions)

---

However, the real story is more complicated than either of those versions:

- The [Monster Lore Compendium](https://web.archive.org/web/20100625000347/http://community.wizards.com:80/go/thread/view/75882/19546370/Monster_Lore_Compendium?pg=1) is a D&D 3.5 resource, so it's probably correct for the question to be tagged as such.
- However, as [linked by the querent](https://web.archive.org/web/20100625000407/http://community.wizards.com:80/go/thread/view/75882/19546370/Monster_Lore_Compendium?pg=63), there really is a claim in that thread that the content would be integrated into "a 3.x project at www.d20pfsrd.com".
- I don't know why people would have been planning to host 3.5 content on a PF site, or if the project ever went anywhere, but that info would be a good start to finding an answer to the querent's original question.

---

Let's hash out what the question should look like, so as to avoid further edit wars.

- How do we want this question to look?
- Should it have the 3.5 tag, the PF tag, or both?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Facts as I understand it are: it's a D&D 3.5e resource, the claims were it would get migrated to d20pfsrd. We should reflect that accurately on both counts. Tagging as just [dnd-3.5e] but not [pathfinder] is accurate. Even if someone mentions d20pfsrd, that doesn't make it a Pathfinder question.

People were surprised and confused and thought there were mistakes here (either the wrong game or the wrong website), so let's switch it back and acknowledge that yes, that's weird, but not a mistake.

I've updated that paragraph to say:

> I have read that it was going to be added to the d20pfsrd (yes, d20pfsrd, even though this is a 3.5e resource), though I don't think that ever happened.